# How to solve YouTUbe video restriction in iOS

Tags: ytplayerview

YouTube video works good in web browser but YTPlayerView shows restriction on iPhone.

[image: screen shot]

Demo URL is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dlzsq9xrRqo&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to, restriction of playing video on mobile from specific region.

You are able to play the video on the browser but not on mobile (even from the same region).

This is Youtube's and not Apple's restriction.

Currently, there is no way to detect the video we requested, is a restricted one through code. But can detect after it displays the message and skip the video, to next video.

Edit:- "origin" : "https://www.example.com" in player variables fixed the above problem